Cannot find the AclBuilder class of android13 Bluetooth
/packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/gd/hci/hci_layer.cc
// Acl packets
BidiQueue<AclView, AclBuilder> acl_queue_ {3 /* TODO: Set queue depth */};
Android13 code
Is there any special way to define it? Can't find where AclView and Ac1Builder are defined.
/packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/gd/hci/hci_layer.cc
